# Changes in my fork got merged but my fork still shows "4 commits ahead"

Tags: git, github

Changes I made on the master branch of my fork got merged into master of the original project ("merged commit 95dd82b into tailwindlabs:master"). I want to make another contribution to this open source project. In the GitHub UI I pressed the "Fetch and merge" button. GitHub UI is still showing the message: "This branch is 4 commits ahead of tailwindlabs:master". Won't this confuse things if I try to make another contribution from this fork? How do I get parity with tailwindlabs:master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [master](https://github.com/o-t-w/tailwindcss/tree/master) branch is a feature branch, not a tracking branch of the upstream [master](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/tree/master). Your `master` feature branch starts at the upstream's [429fe07 commit](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/commit/429fe07a5fe871381dc1), but has diverged since.

It's doubtful to me that using a feature branch named `master` is intentional, and this misnaming is causing your confusion. The giveaway is that you've been merging the upstream's `master` branch into your feature branch. These merges should not exist, but as long as you keep merging, so your feature branch is up to date, you'll be able to create new pull requests without confusing the upstream.

#### A better way to organize your work is:

1. Create a local tracking branch for the upstream `master` (your local branch could be also called `master`)
2. For every feature you want to create, start a new branch, and name it appropriately (eg. `git branch use-text-decoration-line master`), and make your changes there.
3. When your feature is ready to contribute, start your pull-request from the feature branch.
4. Use `git fetch origin` and `git merge origin/master` from your tracking branch named `master` to pick up changes from upstream.

Using this workflow, your `master` log should be identical, down to the commit hashes, to the upstream `master`, and no merging is needed.

#### What if the upstream gets conflicting changes before your feature is ready to contribute?

Before you PR from your feature branch, you should `git rebase` your feature branch onto the updated tracking master branch, and resolve any conflicts. Otherwise, the upstream will have to resolve the conflicts you've introduced. Typically such conflicts are your responsibility to resolve, not the upstream's.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated, because everybody in this story (you and tailwind) behaved badly.

Let's go back to that fateful day when you, on your fork, started adding commits *directly to `master`*, a thing you should never have done:

[image]

As you can see, back on Dec 10, you added a commit (5d15) directly to your own `master`. You then made a further commit on Dec 13 (d309). Those are the two commits that you pushed up into your pull request.

Now let's *look* at your pull request:

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/pull/6378

It's impossible to reconstruct completely what happened here, because it turns out that 5d15 is not the commit you originally submitted. You made some sort of correction by rewriting history, and therefore you had to *force push* the PR branch in order to revise it (on Dec 12 or 13, I can't quite tell which). This should have been a huge red flag, but it wasn't enough, it seems.

Now let's step out of your world into tailwind's world. What happened next is that on Dec 13 your PR was accepted. We see your commit appearing on their `master`:

[image]

We notice, however, two things:

- First, this *isn't* your commit! Even though it has the same message as your first commit, it is a different commit; it is 95dd, whereas your commit with the same message (after the force push) was 5d15, and your second commit was d309.
- Second, this *isn't* a merge! Notice that it has only one parent (the Update Changelog).

So your commit was *not* merged into tailwind's `master`. It was *copied* onto tailwind's `master`. It was *cherry-picked*, not merged at all. Probably tailwind is doing a so-called squash-and-merge here. This is a viable policy for dealing with PRs from a forked version of one's repo, but, despite its name, it is *not a merge*, and therefore it conceals the history — so that once again the tailwind people failed to notice that your branch is called `master`.

The result is that *your* `master` and its topology are completely unaffected by this event. Your branch was *never* merged into tailwind's `master`. In fact, *nothing* in the history connects your commits (5d15 and d309) with tailwind's `master`.

Okay, so at least we are ready to answer the question you originally asked. You are mystified by the status message

```
This branch is 4 commits ahead of tailwindlabs:master
```

But this is no mystery at all, because we can *see* what those 4 commits are! They are *all the commits you have ever made* on your `master`:

[image]

Those are your commits, and (wait for it...) there are four of them! Meanwhile you seem to think that some kind of synchronization should be taking place here, but of course it isn't, because *your* `master` is not tailwind's `master`.

What to do? Well, you should never have made changes directly on `master` to begin with, and the fact that the tailwind people failed to notice that you were making this mistake should have been another red flag for them:

[image]

But that's all water over the dam now. You must simply correct the situation at your end. The simplest way would be to delete your (evil) `master` entirely. But perhaps you would like to preserve your branch for historical purposes. Then just "park" the last "good" commit on that branch by giving it a branch name:

```
git switch -c my-accidental-evil-branch d3095c19
```

Fine. Now get rid of your evil local `master`:

```
git branch -D master
```

Now, if you'd like to start working another feature, do this:

1. Go to your repo at GitHub and update it from the upstream.
2. Return to your local repo and update it:

   ```
    git fetch origin
   ```
3. Now make your feature branch!

   ```
    git switch -c my-cool-feature origin/master
   ```

Now go forth and sin no more.

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. I'm just going to delete the fork and refork.